# How to disable syntax characters in autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to create a program in autohotkey so that when ~pdo is typed it replaces it with a long line of code. How do I do it so that the symbols inside do not get formatted as autohotkey syntax?

I have tried the following code:

```
~pdo:Send,

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=chat;host=localhost', 'root', 'simon sleeping123!@#');
 
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

In return I get the error message:
Line Text: $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);    Error: Invalid hotkey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend utilizing the [clipboard](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm) and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for such a long input. If not pasting the text, you'd need to send that in [text mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Text) to avoid translating certain characters to certain buttons. E.g `#` to the Windows key.
Also, you'll need to add line breaks. More on that below.

Firstly, use a [hotstring](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm) to trigger when `~pdo` is typed. Use whichever [options](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#Options) you see fit. I'd assume you'll be fine with just the [* option](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#Asterisk).

And to send multi line stuff, you can either explicitly specify line breaks with a line feed character `` `n ``<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_EscapeChar.htm#Escape_Sequences)</sup>:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=chat;host=localhost', 'root', 'simon sleeping123!@#');`n`n$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EM...
```

Or you can more conveniently use a [continuation section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#continuation):

```
:*:~pdo::
    Clipboard := "
    (LTrim
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=chat;host=localhost', 'root', 'simon sleeping123!@#');
 
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    )"

    SendInput, ^v
return
```

And there's your finished script. `^v` means <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and the `LTrim`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#LTrim)</sup> option is used do we can still properly format the code without adding extra spaces to the actual text in the continuation section.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Removing all line breaks and replacing them with `n`n got rid of the error messages. Then blind send also helped getting rid of unwanted characters.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a [**Hotstring**](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm) rather than a [**Hotkey**](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotkey.htm). A hotkey triggers when *keys are held down together*, whereas a hotstring triggers when *keys are typed in sequence*.

Furthermore, seeing how this is a multiline hotstring, [take a look at this](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/30600-multiline-hotstring-does-not-work/) to let it work.

Based on this, here is my code (triggered when "~pdo" is typed):

```
:*:~pdo::
MyMultilineHotstring =
(
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=chat;host=localhost', 'root', 'simon sleeping123!@#');
 
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
)
SendInput, %MyMultilineHotstring%
```

Comment: The send command would need to be in text mode.

Comment: When running your code in sublime text it did something weird. It created a new file with half of the data in one file and the other half in the other file. Do you know of any reason for this?